# `h-8` doesn't override `h-4` in Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I created a Icon component as below:

```
import { IconProp, library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { far } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import clsx from "clsx";

library.add(far, fas);

interface IconProps {
  className?: string;
  icon: IconProp;
  shrinkable?: boolean;
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLOrSVGElement>) => void;
}

export function Icon({
  className,
  icon,
  shrinkable = false,
  onClick,
}: IconProps) {
  const defaultClasses = "h-4 w-4";
  const newClasses = clsx(
    defaultClasses,
    { "flex-shrink-0": !shrinkable },
    className
  );

  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon
      className={newClasses}
      icon={icon}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
}
```

As you see the default width and height is 4 (1rem = basically 16px).
The component was designed so that the width and height would be able to to be customized.

The customized usage is below:

```
<Icon
  className="h-8 w-8"
  icon="user-circle"
/>
```

The problem is `h-8` and `w-8` doesn't override `h-4` and `w-4` while other classes like `h-9`, `w-9` or `h-7`, `w-9` surely overrides them.

Look at the screenshots for further understanding.
[image]

However I solved this issue by using `important` - `!h-8` and `!w-8`.
[image]

What's wrong with the code?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try this alongside clsx: https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v1.9.0/docs/what-is-it-for.md

Answer (score 0):

This is simple CSS specificity.

You should apply only classes that don't stomp over each other.
For example, `className={isBig ? 'h-8' : 'h-4'}`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

As noted in the comments below, the need is for the component to accept height classes from the consumer. One option is to use library like `tailwind-merge`.

You can also tackle it like:

```
type Props = {
  heightClass: 'h-1' | 'h-2' | 'h-3' | 'h-4' // all valid options
}

function Icon(props: Props) {
  const { heightClass = 'h-4' } = props;

  return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon className={clsx(
      'flex flex-shrink-0', // base classes
      heightClass: 
    )} />
  );
}
```

If you *really* want consumers to just pass in whatever, then you will need to use `tailwind-merge` or similar. But I would recommend not allowing your consumers to send in random classes (although, it is a common pattern)

Comment: When the dev uses the component, he can pass any prop - not only h-8, but also h-9, h-10, h-11, ...

Comment: In that case, as @ksav as suggested in the comment, you may need additional tooling like tailwind-merge. I will also post an update to address it without libs

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @Chris. I've decided to use tailwind-merge.